# JSON Serialization with accent

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode6

I am facing a trouble when I try getting a remote JSON file with accents. If I take off the accents of the JSON file, it works perfectly, but if I keep them, I have an error. As you are able to verify, I have tried to use "NSUTF8StringEncoding", however, it did not work as well. Any Idea?

```
func getJSON(completionHandler: ((NSArray!, NSError!) -> Void)!) -> Void

{
    var urlAux = "http://www.xxxx.com/downloads/example.json"
    var urlAuxUTF8 = urlAux.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlAuxUTF8!)
    let ses = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    var enc:NSStringEncoding = NSUTF8StringEncoding
    var error: NSError?

    let content = NSString.stringWithContentsOfURL(url, usedEncoding:&enc, error:&error)

    if (error != nil)
    {
        NSLog("error: %@", error!)
        exit(-1)
    }
    else
    {
        let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(content.dataUsingEncoding(enc)!, options:nil, error: &error) as NSDictionary

        if (error != nil) {
            return completionHandler(nil, error)
        } else {
            return completionHandler(json["express"] as [NSDictionary], nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you be more clear? I did not get, what exactly is duplicated. I am swift learner. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have perfectly fine NSData, you convert it to a string and have to guess the encoding, then you convert it to NSData again. Use a function that gets the NSData directly, without any conversion to a string, and pass it to NSJSONSerialization as it is.